# Give Apache permission to write to files

Tags: php, apache, content-management-system, chown, respondcms

I am trying to install `respondCMS`, and it tells me that I need to give apache permission to write files.

I cd'ed to the `htdocs` folder, and ran this terminal command

```
chown -R apache /sites
```

but it says `chown: apache: illegal user name`.

Answer (score 2):

Apache user usually is not named apache, but www or www-data. Check it out by doing:

cat /etc/apache2/envvars | grep USER

Comment: I am using `MAMP` and I copied that command right from the `respondCMS`'s documentation.

Comment: just look into apache's conf file (apache.conf, apache2.conf, httpd.conf... whatever...) for APACHE_RUN_USER variable which will tell you which user is actually the apache user

Comment: It still can't write files.

Comment: Ok. Say the user is www-data. Once you are in the htdocs folder: `chown -R www-data .` and `chmod u+w . -R`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MAMP on a Mac (I assume, as the Windows version is still very much beta), then you need to change the file permissions to your own username and the group staff. That's how MAMP runs Apache. On "real" LAMP Stacks this would be very different.

So if your Mac user name is "mendocino", change the permissions in that directory with

```
chown -R mendocino:staff /sites
```

Comment: I have my files set like this on my mac but I am unable to upload media. I tried to use apache www but got the illegal error. So why cant I upload if the username and group are correct ?